# How to take and put image from one ImageView to another

Tags: android

I want to take picture from second activity imageView and put it in MainActivity imageView. How to put it? Hope my code of taking it is right.

Main Activity

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_PLAYER1:
                String name1 = data.getStringExtra("name");
                playerName1.setText(name1);
                btnPlayer1.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt("photo"));
```

Second Activity

public void onClick(View v) {

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.axe:
            intent.putExtra("name", axeName.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("photo", R.drawable.axe);
            break;
```

Comment: Did you mean get the image's drawable? or take image from whole second activity?

Comment: Please do not use images of code (and especially hosted on external sites) - instead copy/paste it into your question.  This will make the question much easier to answer and more useful for those who find it in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo can get Image like.

```
 btnPlayer1.setImageResource(data.getIntExtra("photo",0));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are best)